# PHP won't read full file into array, only partial

Tags: php, arrays, csv, coredump

I have a file with 3,200,000 lines of csv data (with 450 columns). Total file size is 6 GB.

I read the file like this:

```
$data = file('csv.out');
```

Without fail, it only reads 897,000 lines. I confirmed with 'print_r', and `echo sizeof($data)`. I increased my "memory_limit" to a ridiculous value like 80 GB but didn't make a difference.

Now, it DID read in my other large file, same number of lines (3,200,000) but only a few columns so total file size 1.1 GB.  So it appears to be a total file size issue. FYI, 897,000 lines in the $data array is around 1.68 GB.

Update: I increased the second (longer) file to 2.1 GB (over 5 million lines) and it reads it in fine, yet truncates the other file at 1.68 GB. So does not appear to be a size issue.  If I continue to increase the size of the second file to 2.2 GB, instead of truncating it and continuing the program (like it does for the first file), it dies and core dumps.

Update: I verified my system is 64 bit by printing integer and float numbers:

```
<?php
$large_number = 2147483647;
var_dump($large_number);                     // int(2147483647)

$large_number = 2147483648;
var_dump($large_number);                     // float(2147483648)

$million = 1000000;
$large_number =  50000 * $million;
var_dump($large_number);                     // float(50000000000)

$large_number = 9223372036854775807;
var_dump($large_number);                     //         
int(9223372036854775807)

$large_number = 9223372036854775808;
var_dump($large_number);                     //
float(9.2233720368548E+18)

$million = 1000000;
$large_number =  50000000000000 * $million;
var_dump($large_number);                     // float(5.0E+19)

print "PHP_INT_MAX: " . PHP_INT_MAX . "\n";
print "PHP_INT_SIZE: " . PHP_INT_SIZE . " bytes (" . (PHP_INT_SIZE * 8)     . "     bits)\n";

?>
```

The output from this script is:

int(2147483647)

int(2147483648)

int(50000000000)

int(9223372036854775807)

float(9.2233720368548E+18)

float(5.0E+19)

PHP_INT_MAX: 9223372036854775807

PHP_INT_SIZE: 8 bytes (64 bits)

So since it's 64 bit, and memory limit is set really high, why is PHP not reading files > 2.15 GB?

Comment: 1) Are you sure you need to read the whole file? Can you split your task into the small parts and read the file line by line? 2) You may read the file line by line and store the lines into the `SplDoublyLinkedList` or `SplFixedArray` instead of default array to reduce the RAM requirements.

Comment: Rather than reading the entire file into memory, I'd recommend using a file-pointer function like [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: As for your question, unfortunately I can't find any references to specific limits on `file()` but you would expect it is limited by available memory capacity.

Comment: It's an enormous server with lots of memory.  I'll have to try your suggestion though. Just seems like there is a per-file memory limit, since I raised the "memory_limit" to such a huge value, and the problem persists.

Comment: The reason I'm reading it into memory is because it has to do a huge nested loop. I have to compare each of the 3.2 million lines to each of the other 3.2 million lines. So not sure if the alternate methods above would be fast as memory? If so I will try. Otherwise, I may have to rewrite the whole thing in C :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. All I had to do was change the way I read the files. Why...I do not know.

Old code that only reads 2.15 GB out of 6.0 GB:

```
$data = file('csv.out');
```

New code that reads the full 6.0 GB:

```
$data = array();

$i=1;
$handle = fopen('csv.out');

if ($handle) {
while (($data[$i] = fgets($handle)) !== false){
  // process the line read
  $i++;
}
```

Feel free to shed some light on why. There must be some limitation when using

```
$var=file();
```

Interestingly, 2.15 GB is close to the 32 bit limit I read about.

Answer (score 3):

Some things that come to mind:

- If you're using a 32 bits PHP, you cannot read files that are larger than 2GB.
- If reading the file takes too long, there could be time-outs.
- If the file is really huge, then reading it all into memory is going to be problematic. It's usually better to read blocks of data and process that, unless you need random access to all parts of the file.
- Another approach (i've used that in the past), is to chop the large file into smaller, more manageable ones (should work if it's a straightforwards log file for example)

Comment: It is 64 bit PHP. And reading the files only takes about 15 seconds.